# Program crashes at dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have a program in which there is a tableViewController which has 1 section and 3 rows. Whenever I run the app, it always crashes at `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` method. I inserted a breakpoint and `NSLog()` to zero in the this method. I also set the `Cell Identifier` of the prototype cell in storyboard to `Cell`. But the program still crashes. Here's an method that is causing the problem:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"indexPath.section = %d, indexPath.row = %d", indexPath.section, indexPath.row);
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"in nil");
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

The crash log reads:

```
MyAppTake4[7463:707] indexPath.section = 0, indexPath.row = 0
2012-11-05 23:21:20.747 MyCardAppTake4[7463:707] -[UITableView     dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance     0xfbc9000
2012-11-05 23:21:20.753 MyCardAppTake4[7463:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught     exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableView     dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance     0xfbc9000'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x3254788f 0x3459d259 0x3254aa9b 0x32549915 0x324a4650 0x7e2f7 0x31fceefb 0x31fcdfd9     0x31fcd763 0x31f71f15 0x324a61fb 0x3420aaa5 0x3420a6bd 0x3420e843 0x3420e57f 0x342064b9     0x3251bb1b 0x32519d57 0x3251a0b1 0x3249d4a5 0x3249d36d 0x315f4439 0x31f9ccd5 0x7d9f9 0x7d994)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

I am interested in identifying the exact cause of error so that I do not make this mistake again.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The `UITableView` method `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` was added in iOS 6.0. Are you getting this error under iOS 5.x?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thats because [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath]; was added in iOS 6 but not recognized by iOS 5. For iOS 5 compatibility use below method instead:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

Comment: `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` is a perfectly valid method as of iOS 6.0.

Comment: thanks cyberpawn.. it worked. Just bu removing ` forIndexPath:indexPath`, the program started working. this method was present by default when I created a new file with subclass of `UITableViewController`. If  `forIndexPath:indexPath` is the culprit, why is it present in the program by default?

Comment: since ur comment helped me identify the problem first, I have accepted your answer. I am also thankful to other for roping in! :-)

Comment: @Rut thanks, i think you created your project with Xcode 4.5 thats why it was created by default for You.

Comment: This answer doesn't explain why it crashes, nor the error. `dequeueResuableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath` is perfectly valid, so the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: This is stupid. You should definitely the prescribed method. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15768903/563381

Comment: @RyanPoolos thanks for your input but the problem here was that OP was using this method in iOS 5 but the method got introduced in iOS 6.. causing unrecognized selector crash.. I understand in the answer i didn't explained the issue well.. I have edited the answer!

Answer (score 7):

Did you register the class of the cell or the nib first?

From the Apple docs:

Important: You must register a class or nib file using the registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier: or registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier: method before calling this method.

(btw that method is only available in iOS 6)

If you're using iOS 6, then you can use the new simpler paradigm:

In viewDidLoad, register the class, in your case, that's just the UITableViewCell class:

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

Then, you can just do it like this in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = self.myArray[indexPath.row];
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I had registered the class of the viewController. There are no `nib` since I am using storyboard. `cyberpawn` helped me find out the error. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Adding the `registerClass` method in my `viewDidLoad` did the trick for me. Thx.

Comment: This only works for a specific cell instance, not for a prototype? :(

Comment: @ZackWeiner, not sure what your comment refers to. If you make the cell in a storyboard, you shouldn't register anything. Register the class if the cell is made entirely in code, and register the nib if the cell is made in a xib file.

Answer (score 1):

Since forIndexPath method is for ios6, I recommend you to use this snipet. Find below.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [table_view dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

    // **initialize** your stuff here **with their respected tag**
}
else
{
   // **get** your stuff back using their tags
}
// **assign** your valiues here

return cell;
```

Enjoy Programming

Answer (score 0):

I had this exception, and realised that it was caused by my stupid mistake.  I had created a blank .xib file (to have a custom "Loading" cell in my `UITableView`), but had then drag'n'dropped a `View` into it.  Doh!

The result was the exception message which you're seeing, plus this in the Output window:

```
2014-04-25 20:45:12.953 Languages[36256:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught 
exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'invalid nib registered
for identifier (LoadingCell) - nib must contain exactly one top level object 
which must be a UITableViewCell instance'
```

The solution, of course, was to add a `Table View Cell` to my .xib file, copy the other UI components into it, and just leave that Table View Cell as the "root" element in the file.

Comment: Yup, I accidentally did the same.   My .xib file was perfect... but I'd mistakenly drag'n'dropped a label onto the .xib, outside of the main view.  (Sigh.)   Chalk up another wasted hour.

Answer (score 0):

Another cause for this error can be-

invalid nib registered for identifier (Cell) - nib must contain exactly one top level object which must be a UICollectionReusableView instance

I had a UIView in my xib instead of a collectionViewCell. Hope this helps.