# UITableView shows blank cells even when cellForRowAtIndexPath is called properly

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a very strange problem and I've got a feeling it's going to be a weird solution like I have the wrong provisioning profile (checked that!).

I can run on the Simulator and one of my iPhone 5's and I have a UITableView populating with some cells, all playing nice.

However, I've just run it on my 5S and the table view is completely blank. The cells aren't selectable or anything. I've checked the TableView isn't getting released or anything, and it is responsive if I pull down to refresh. I can even see my logging saying the numberOfRows... and cellForRow.. methods are getting called again if I pull to refresh, just no UI is displayed at all!

Here's various snippets in case this helps:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
...
    UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"EJCMatchInboxCell" bundle:nil];
    [self.matchTable registerNib:cellNib forCellReuseIdentifier:kEJCMatchInboxCellIdent];

    UINib *segmentedCellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"EJCSegmentedControlCell" bundle:nil];
    [self.matchTable registerNib:segmentedCellNib forCellReuseIdentifier:kEJCMatchInboxSegmentedControlCellIdent];
...
    self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    [self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.matchTable addSubview:self.refreshControl];
...
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section == 0) {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}

- (long)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (long)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    long rowCount = matches.count + 1;
    NSLog(@"MatchInboxVC::numberOfRowsInSection %li", rowCount);
    return rowCount;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"MatchInboxVC::cellForRowAtIndexPath %li", indexPath.row);

    if(indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section == 0) {
        // segmented control cell
        EJCSegmentedControlCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kEJCMatchInboxSegmentedControlCellIdent];

        // Configure the cell...
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[EJCSegmentedControlCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:kEJCMatchInboxSegmentedControlCellIdent];
        }

        [cell.segmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:selectedSegmentIndex];
        [cell.segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(changedSegmentSelection:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        [cell.segmentedControl setTitle:@"Current" forSegmentAtIndex:0];
        [cell.segmentedControl setTitle:@"Deleted" forSegmentAtIndex:1];

        return cell;
    }
    else {
        // match cell
        EJCMatchInboxCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kEJCMatchInboxCellIdent];

        // Configure the cell...
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[EJCMatchInboxCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:kEJCMatchInboxCellIdent];
        }

        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

        EJCMatch *m = matches[indexPath.row - 1];
        [cell setupWithMatch:m];

        return cell;
    }
}

- (float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section == 0) {
        return 38.0f;
    }
    else {
        return 65.0f;
    }
}
```

Logging output:

```
MatchInboxVC::numberOfRowsInSection 2
MatchInboxVC::cellForRowAtIndexPath 0
MatchInboxVC::cellForRowAtIndexPath 1
```

Comment: I've just noticed this is happening for every table view in the app - all of them work on the iPhone 5 and in the simulator, none work on the 5S???

Comment: I've also done a complete reset of the simulator to check it wasn't caching the XIB file for the cells or something - and it still works perfectly on the Simulator. Deleted the app from the 5S and re-ran but still not working.

Comment: When you register NIB's like that, I don't think you need the `if(cell==nil)` check in cellForRowAtIndexPath. You're guaranteed a cell. So try removing that IF statement, including what's inside it.

Comment: Interesting - I thought dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier would return nil unless there is a cell actually available in the recycle queue?

Comment: I think this SO answer explains it well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13199507/2410991

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right - I guess this was my own fault for forgetting to read the method definition properly, but apparently setting a return type of (float) for heightForRowAtIndexPath on the 5S will prevent the cells displaying at all.

Solved by changing the method definition from

```
- (float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

to

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: Very very strange that the behaviour is different on two devices running iOS7. Just checked and the device that broke is running 7.0.4 and the device it was working on anyway is running 7.0, so they must have introduced something between those versions..